# A function to fill an hash table

Tags: c, hashtable

For homework I have to create a function with no arguments, in order to fill a hash table with `NULL`.
This is the declaration of the table (I can't change it), and how I call the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

int main()
{
  char* htab[MAX];
  htab = mkempty();
}
```

and this is the function that I created

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

char* mkempty()
{
  char* ensemble[MAX];
  int i=0;
  for (i=0;i<MAX;i++) 
  {
    ensemble[i]=NULL; 
  }
  return ensemble;
}
```

when I compiled it I got this:

```
 error: assignment to expression with array type
  htab=mkempty();
```

I understand the error but I don't know how to fill this table.

The declaration has to be: `char* htab[MAX];`, and the function doesn't have any argument.

Comment: What do you expect happens with the **local** variable `ensemble` when your function returns? And an array is not a pointer! Also your function has to be declared before usage. If your compiler does not complain, use a modern compiler and enable all recommended warnings and treat them like errors. Read about pointers, arrrays, functions … actually all basics. Minor flaw: Functions which don't take parameters should use `(void)`, not `()`. The latter is obsolete and to be removed in a future version.

Comment: Are you sure you're interpreting the instructions correctly? Can you link to the original assignment?

Comment: the description of the fonction : 
mkempty: has no argument; creates an empty string set .                                    
In this exercise a string set is implemented by means of a hash table, here such a table is declared as

Comment: There is too much wrong. You seem to have missinterpreted the assignment or it is flawed. Ask your teacher for advice, it will no way work this way.

Comment: @thibox2225 Is `char* htab[MAX]; htab = mkempty();` specified in the assignment? Or is that your own code?

Comment: @Schwern `char* htab[MAX];` is specified , `htab = mkempty();` is my own code.

Answer (score 2):

Given the table:

```
char* htab[MAX];
```

The best way to set it all to NULL is:

```
memset(htab, 0, sizeof(htab));
```

If you need to do it inside a function,  your function must take the array as a pointer plus size:

```
void mkempty(char** array, size_t count)
{
    memset(array, 0, count * sizeof(char*));
}
```

Which is then called like this:

```
mkempty(htab, MAX);
```

Now, some people will tell you that "zeroing" a pointer does not necessarily make it NULL.  These pedants are correct: the above use of `memset()` technically relies on something which may not be true on 100% of all machines ever made.  Specifically, it will not work on some large computers made between 20 and 50 years ago.  I presume your homework is not being run on computers from the 1980s.

Comment: Ok, but I can't give arguments to my function.That's why I want to create `char* ensemble[MAX];` and put "ensemble" elements in "htab"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have an assignment you can just use the pointer and dynamically allocate the memory instead. No arguments

```
char **mkempty(void)
{
    return calloc(MAX, sizeof(char *));
}
```

and in the main

```
char **htop;
htop = mkempty();
```

Comment: the declaration of the hash table has to be `char* htab[MAX];`

Comment: so you cant assign anything to the array variable . Mayme you did not understand something - ask the teacher

Answer (score 0):

so I asked my teacher and he does not want a function without argument, it's a mistake on the sheet he gave me

so my function will be :

```
void mkempty(char** htab[])
{
  int i=0;
  for (i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++){
    *htab[i]=NULL;
  }
}
```